# Cocos2DX --> Layer Instantiates Scene?

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

Reading books and topics on Cocos2dx everyone seems to be teaching it like so:

1. Create a class that inherits from CCLayer
2. Within that CCLayer class, instantiate a Static SCENE
3. Add layout to scene

Metaphorically, it is like the Egg creates its Parent.  This seems backwards, non-intuitive.  Why not just do this:

1. Create a class that inherits from CCScene (call it GameScene)
2. Create another class that inherits from CCLayer (call it GameLayer)
3. The GameScene class is a singleton (has a singleton member: static GameScene* scene)
4. Instantiate the GameLayer class within the GameScene class

The GameLayer class will have the usual suspects: UPDATE, INIT, etc. and the GameScene class with have INIT and it's static self-referencing member.

While this may seem like more work, it really isn't and logically makes more sense, furthermore, it affords the developer a place, to place SCENE specific logic, and LAYER specific logic.

Are there any issues doing it this way?  Why are so many teaching it backwards?

**EXAMPLE**:

**# GameScene**

```
#ifndef __GameScene__
#define __GameScene__

#include "cocos2d.h"
using namespace cocos2d;

class GameScene : public cocos2d::CCScene
{

public:
    ~GameScene();
    virtual bool init();
    static GameScene* scene();
    CREATE_FUNC(GameScene);
};

#endif /* defined(__GameScene__) */

#include "GameScene.h"
#include "GameLayer.h"

GameScene::~GameScene() {}

GameScene* GameScene::scene()
{
    GameScene *scene = GameScene::create();
    GameLayer *layer = GameLayer::create();
    scene->addChild(layer);
    return scene;
}

bool GameScene::init()
{
    if (!CCScene::init()) return false;
    return true;
}
```

**# GameLayer**

```
#ifndef __GAMELAYER_H__
#define __GAMELAYER_H__

#include "cocos2d.h"

using namespace cocos2d;

class GameLayer : public cocos2d::CCLayer
{
public:
    ~GameLayer();        
    virtual bool init();
    virtual void draw();
    void update(float dt);        
    CREATE_FUNC(GameLayer);
};

#endif // __GAMELAYER_H__

#include "GameLayer.h"

GameLayer::~GameLayer() {}

bool GameLayer::init()
{
    if (!CCLayer::init())
        return false;

    this->schedule(schedule_selector(GameLayer::update));
    return true;
}

void GameLayer::draw() {}

void GameLayer::update(float dt) {}
```

**And finally within the AppDelegate CPP**

```
bool AppDelegate::applicationDidFinishLaunching()
{
    // initialize director
    ...
    ...

    // Create a scene
    GameScene *pScene = GameScene::scene();

    // Run
    pDirector->runWithScene(pScene);
    return true;
}
```

I also have a thread on this topic on cocos2dx:

> http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/layer-instantiates-scene/18149/4

Comment: Did you mean CCLayer instead of CCLayout? What version of cocos2d-x is this? Normally the CCScene instance is at the root of the hierarchy. If there's a book that does it differently it's probably just doing it wrong, but I can't say for sure without seeing it. Can you name the book or add a link to a tutorial that does it the "weird way"?

Comment: Corrected "Layout" typos.

Comment: When you create a new project, the default template code is setup the "weird way". It is also taught in like that in "Cocos2d-X by Example Beginner's Guide", by Rodger Engelbert.

Comment: And you can see examples of it here, where a "GameScene" class is created but it inherits from CCLayer.  http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/User_Tutorial-Create_a_new_scene_or_layer_transition

Comment: I'm nearly certain there isn't an issue with the way I'm proposing in my question, but maybe there's something else I'm not yet understanding about the framework and why it's taught the way it generally is? (or maybe it's just out of tradition that it's taught the way it is?

Comment: added an answer, let me know if anything remains unclear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Rodger Engelbert** author of **Cocos2d-x by Example, Beginners Guide** responded to this question via email.

> Hi Jason,
>
> There is no need to follow the strategy used in the template. In fact
>   I don't know anyone who does it outside the Cocos2d-x group and I only
>   ever used it in the examples for the book for consistency.
>
> A Scene is unique, and it's what the director requires to run. It's
>   possible to have two scenes running during transitions, but otherwise
>   a scene is structurally treated as One block in your architecture. You
>   may or may not organize your project into multiple blocks, but you
>   will need at least one.
>
> But you're free to do it in any way you wish. You might use scenes
>   more prominently, as some developers do or use one only, for the sake
>   of the Director, and focus on master Layer objects. Also, keep in mind
>   that the generated code in the template is only trying to give you a
>   canvas as quickly as possible. It's not necessary the best starting
>   point for your project. It's up to you to make that decision.
>
> Roger

Answer (score 4):

There is a confusion between base class names and the subclass names.

For instance in the [cocos2d-x wiki](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/User_Tutorial-Create_a_new_scene_or_layer_transition) they subclass from `Layer` (CCLayer) but they name this `Layer` subclass `GameScene` even though it isn't an actual scene, it's a layer. Further down they create the actual Scene (CCScene) instance with the call to `createScene`, which I assume returns a generic Scene instance with the GameScene instance added to the scene:

```
auto scene = GameScene::createScene();
Director::getInstance()->replaceScene(scene);
```

So you do end up with the following hierarchy:

```
Scene
    Layer (custom class: GameScene)
        Nodes...
```

Now the origin of this weird naming philosophy is simply that it has been going around in the cocos2d community for ages. In very early cocos2d-iphone project templates you had a `HelloWorldScene` class that inherited from `CCLayer`. It contained a class method `scene` that created an instance of `CCScene`, created a `HelloWorldScene` instance and added it to the generic scene instance before returning it.

So basically this is simply a confusion due to badly named subclasses in project templates, tutorials and books. Against all rational thought the "tradition" prevailed in cocos2d-x. In cocos2d-iphone this was eventually fixed (in v2.x I believe) by renaming the template class to `HelloWorldLayer`.

Comment: Good explanation and what I thought... tradition. Logically, it makes more sense to lay it out the way I propose. Totally agree; calling a class a "scene" when it subclasses a layer is darn confusing, but it's also confusing to call it a layer then return a singleton of scene (its parent). I'll be breaking that tradition. :)